# curl with json array

Tags: json, bash, curl

The first command works and the second doesn't.  What do I need to change to allow the json array to work?  Thank you in advance.

command #1:

```
curl -d '{"uid":"TEST", "object":"TEST"}' \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST http://WEBSERVER/api/v1/inventory
```

command #2

```
curl -d '{"uid":"TEST","object":["server1", "server2", "server3"]}' \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST http://WEBSERVER/api/v1/inventory
```

Comment: For future note -- backticks are for code formatting strings which are less than a single line in length. Use the `{}` button in the editor with a multi-line block selected, or add four spaces before each line, for longer segments. This gets you colorized syntax highlighting and generally better-looking formatting.

Comment: That said, in terms of what content a server allows -- that's the server's decision; it's not something bash or curl has any say in. If you can reproduce a problem with a publicly-available service that is explicitly documented to allow arrays, that would put us in a better place (in terms of being able to reproduce a [mcve] -- roughly, the shortest possible code that someone else can run to see a problem themselves, or use to test whether their proposed answer actually fixes a problem).

Comment: (Also, "doesn't work" is not much of a description to go off of -- it doesn't tell us if you got an error from curl itself or from the remote server, f/e, and that distinction is critical. Please be sure that you provide the *exact* error you're asking about, going forward).

Answer (score 2):

Your curl syntax  is fine, you could test by using [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/), for example:

```
$ curl -d '{"uid":"TEST","object":["server1", "server2", "server3"]}' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST http://httpbin.org/post
```

Returns:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"uid\":\"TEST\",\"object\":[\"server1\", \"server2\", \"server3\"]}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "57",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  },
  "json": {
    "object": [
      "server1",
      "server2",
      "server3"
    ],
    "uid": "TEST"
  },
  "origin": "x.x.x.x",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

You indeed could pipe the result and verify the output with your input:

```
$ curl -d '{"uid":"TEST","object":["server1", "server2", "server3"]}' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST http://httpbin.org/post -s | jq -r '.data'
```

It will print:

```
{"uid":"TEST","object":["server1", "server2", "server3"]}
```

Probably the server you are using to post data don't accept your request, check the returned status code, could give a clue, maybe is a 400 (bad request) or a 406 (not acceptable) etc, just in case here is a list of possible [status codes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)